# I am trying to execute the following code in C# but its somehow giving me an error

Tags: c#, namespaces

```
namespace A
{
       public enum ABC
       {
       }
       public class ClassA
       {
            static ClassA()
            {}
            public static bool f_name
            {
            }
             //All the rest of the functions are also static
       }
}

namespace B
{
       using A;
       public partial class ClassB
       {
              private bool x;
              public ClassB()
              {}
              static void Main()
              {
                      x = ClassA.f_name;
              }
       }
}
```

both the namespaces are in different files. On running this code, ClassA.f_name doesn't work. It's ignored somehow. When I put a watch on it, it says this "The name 'ClassA' does not exist in the current context". Can anyone tell me why ? also what do I need to do to fix this ?

When I used "A.ClassA.f_name", then it worked fine. But I shouldn't need to write "A." since I included namespace A already. Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm running this in Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7. I have put the build order such that namespace A is compiled before namespace B.

Comment: Are these in different assemblies? Your comment about build order tells me that you probably have a project/solution setup problem, not a code problem.

Comment: Your code has couple of problems, first `f_name`, if it is a field then remove `{}` and if it is a method then put `()`, also in `ClassB`, you are trying to access an instance member in static method.

Comment: yes they are in different assemblies. yes this is part of a bigger project. im not able to fix this part. i actually want access to ClassA functions in the entire project

Comment: @user2945623: If your code doesn't compile and doesn't properly exhibit the problem then its hard for us to help. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for some hints on what to include in an answer. In particular providing complete code for a program that exhibits this behaviour is always going to get you much better help...

Comment: the code compiles just fine. but it doesn't work as desired. when i debugged it and put a watch on Class.f_name it said "The name 'ClassA' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is due to the fact that you need to access the static class `A` with a non static variable `x`. chnage your classes to:

```
namespace A
{
    public enum ABC
    {
    }
    public class ClassA
    {
        static ClassA()
        { }
        public static bool f_name
        {
           get { return true; }
        }

        //All the rest of the functions are also static
    }
}

namespace B
{
    using A;
    public partial class ClassB
    {
        /// changed this to static to match access on class A
        private static bool x;
        public ClassB()
        { }
        static void Main()
        {
            x = ClassA.f_name;
        }
    }
}
```

and all will be fine

Comment: @jimtollan: Given that apparently the original code worked by adding `A.` before the `ClassA` I'm not sure that the problem is what you think or that the OP's code is actually what he has above so C&P might not be easy.

Comment: i forgot to mention that both the namespaces are in different assemblies. the weirdest part is i can access the enum part just fine but not ClassA.

Comment: well, curiousity got the better of me and i opened a console app and pasted both your code and my code in. my theory bears fruit and it all works, using A.ClassA doesn't work. sorry for being a pedant, but i was certain my quick scan was correct. please trust me on this static business!! :-)

Comment: based on your example given, (lterally creating a new console app and adding the code), then the above remedies that. if there's something that is outside that code paste, then i'm afraid i can only guess and surmise beyond the evidence you've presented.

Answer (score 0):

you are using two different namespaces .hence it got resolved when you added reference to namespace A.

Comment: but do i still need to add "A." even if ive used "using A" ?

Comment: You don't need to add A if you are already referring it , just refresh and see if it works.

Comment: thats the problem its not working without the "A." i dont know why. the enum works fine without A. but not ClassA